# Occasionally no templates in Salesforce document generate

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, salesforce

We are using Salesforce with Apttus.  Actually, I am automating a Google Chrome test using java and Selenium.  I create the documents, send to Docusign for signatures, etc.

Part of the test is to create an agreement (by filling in many fields) which I imagine can be different for each implementation.  Then we click the "Generate Supporting Document" button, which I assume is common for all Salesforce implementations.

Clicking the Generate button brings you to a page where you select format (DOCX, PDF, etc), protection, watermark and a template, and then click "generate" (this is a different generate from what was just clicked).  The actual template choices depend on the specific implementation, but the functionality (list of templates to select) should be the same for all implementations.

Anyway, this part generally works, but occasionally, an empty page shows up (no place to chose format, protection, etc. and no templates to choose from).

My guess is some SOAP message failed or did not return in time, so no data is displayed, but I am not sure this is the case.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  I can't just click GENERATE again, because it has already gone to a new page.

Comment: Shouldnt your test case stop there and open a bug? do you want to proceed further?

Comment: It happens only sporadically.  They actually want me to start the jenkins test over if it fails there, but I am not sure how to do that.